# Не могу подключить webhook для Телеграм бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, webhook

```
curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot***/setWebhook" --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data-raw "{"url": "https://9d72aa7d478e.ngrok.io"}"

выдает
```

{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook is already deleted"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в Вашем URL. В метод setWebhook не нужно передавать тело запроса:

```bsh
curl --location --request POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setWebhook?url=<URL>"
```

И удалите Ваш токен бота из вопроса :)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло